# Implement an interface in a class with additional methods

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface

I'm trying to embrace clean code and design patterns and came across to the following scenario.

My interface

```
interface SystemLogInterface
{
    public function log(string $type);
}
```

And my `class` implementation

```
class LogDownloadService implements SystemLogInterface
{
  public function log(string $type)){}
}
```

I have another logging `class`, similar to the one above.

```
class LogUserService
{
  public function setAttr(){}
  public function log(string $type)){}
}
```

Because this class has an extra method `setAttr()` it does not implement same `interface`.

For example, let's suppose that my `LogUserService` `class` was implementing `SystemLogInterface`

```
public function foo(LogUserService $service)
{
 $service->setAttr($this->getAttr())
 $service->log()
}
```

If I want to change the injected service to another implementation, i would have to change the body of the method `foo()`,  because the `setAttr()` method will not exist.

I want to achieve, if possible, a result to have both classes implementing the same interface or another solution.

**Note:** `setAttr(`) can not be moved to the constructor

Comment: Please, try to fix the little details in the code, so we know there are no issues stemming from typos and whatnot. None of those `log()` methods are compatible with the interface they are meant to implement.

Comment: And the whole design is suspect. What's exactly what you need to do? Does `foo()` have to deal both with objects that implement `setAttr()` and objects that do not implement it? Or whatever you are passing to that method will always have a `setAttr()` method, and the problem is that that method does not exist in the `SystemLogInterface`?

Comment: _"If I want to change the interface implementation I will need to also change the body of the method, which is wrong."_. What do you mean by this? Please edit your question and clarify matters.

Comment: @yivi ouch, you are right, i had to review my question. I have made some edits. Please let me know if its clear now.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding the point of interfaces.

An interface, in effect, defines the contract between classes. This has two perspectives for classes:

- in class, that **implements** an interface, it indicates what capabilities the has. And each class can implement multiple interfaces, some of which will be unrelated and some of which will overlap.
- in class, that **requires** an interface, it indicates *which* specific capabilities the following code will need from a given object.

So ... how I would approach this.

You need to create another interface, that contains your `setAttr` method (let's call it: `WithAttributes`). Then you need to create an interface, that inherits `SystemLogInterface` and `WithAttribures`.

This "composite interface" would be the one that your `LogUserService` actually implements. And you would be able to then pass the instance of it both to the methods, that require the new;y created composite AND the old code requiring the `SystemLogInterface` functionality.

---

P.S. why do you call your interface `SystemLogInterface` but not your class `LogUserServiceClass` .... you really should be more consistent :P